# Does .NET nanoFramework on ESP32 support generics

Tags: nanoframework

I'm attempting to write a C# application with a generic class, targeting ESP32. When launching the debugger, the Visual Studio nanoFramework extension's debug process appears to be stuck in an infinite loop at the "Loading Deployment Assemblies" step.

Here's the output I see in the VS2019 debug window:

```
Waiting for nanoDevice to initialize...
Debugger found. Resuming boot sequence.
Create Type System.
Loading Deployment Assemblies.
   Assembly: Esp32NanoframeworkScratch (1.0.0.0)   (212 RAM - 488 ROM - 226 METADATA)

   AssemblyRef    =        4 bytes (       1 elements)
   TypeRef        =        8 bytes (       2 elements)
   FieldRef       =        4 bytes (       1 elements)
   MethodRef      =       16 bytes (       4 elements)
   TypeDef        =       16 bytes (       2 elements)
   FieldDef       =        4 bytes (       1 elements)
   MethodDef      =       12 bytes (       5 elements)
   StaticFields   =        0 bytes (       0 elements)

   Attributes      =        0 bytes (       0 elements)
   TypeSpec        =        0 bytes (       0 elements)
   Resources       =        0 bytes (       0 elements)
   Resources Files =        0 bytes (       0 elements)
   Resources Data  =        0 bytes
   Strings         =       96 bytes
   Signatures      =       22 bytes
   ByteCode        =       40 bytes


   Assembly: mscorlib (1.10.3.0)   (3948 RAM - 31220 ROM - 18795 METADATA)

   AssemblyRef    =        0 bytes (       0 elements)
   TypeRef        =        0 bytes (       0 elements)
   FieldRef       =        0 bytes (       0 elements)
   MethodRef      =        0 bytes (       0 elements)
   TypeDef        =     1112 bytes (     139 elements)
   FieldDef       =      200 bytes (      99 elements)
   MethodDef      =     1568 bytes (     783 elements)
   StaticFields   =      144 bytes (      12 elements)

   Attributes      =       40 bytes (       5 elements)
   TypeSpec        =        4 bytes (       1 elements)
   Resources       =        0 bytes (       0 elements)
   Resources Files =        0 bytes (       0 elements)
   Resources Data  =        0 bytes
   Strings         =     2609 bytes
   Signatures      =     2095 bytes
   ByteCode        =     9686 bytes


Resolving.
   Assembly: mscorlib (1.10.3.0)   (3948 RAM - 31220 ROM - 18795 METADATA)
…(repeats the mscorlib assembly table forever)
```

The default NFProject template builds, launches, and debugs without issue on my hardware. However, adding a generic class causes the infinite loop shown above:

```cs
using System.Threading;

namespace Esp32NanoframeworkScratch
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            _ = new GenericBox<object> { Value = new object() };
            Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        class GenericBox<T>
        {
            public T Value { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

This repro is not affected by whether the generic class is inner, nor by the specific type parameter used. The problem also reproduces if I instantiate and invoke a `Func<T>`.

---

I note that [in 2018](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/net-core-and-net-standard-for-iot-the-potential-of-the-meadow-kickstarter) (see the final comment below the article) a member of the nanoFramework project reported that generics were *not* supported. However, I'm not able to find any documentation regarding generics support / non-support. Searching around I've found [this merged pull request](https://github.com/nanoframework/nf-interpreter/pull/1802) that appears to add support for generics, and [this blog post](https://blog.devmobile.co.nz/2020/10/04/cayenne-low-power-payload-lpp-encoder/) that describes support for `System.Collections.Generic` and Linq to be "inconsistent".

Does nanoframework currently support generics? And if not, does the project intend to support generics in the future?

Comment: Seems that [in January 2019](https://github.com/nanoframework/Home/issues/450#issuecomment-458988219) the answer was "generics are not supported"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics support it's on the works. Currently the only missing piece is adding support of it in the VS debugger library. We plan to tackle that soon.

Comment: Sounds great — and thanks for your work on nanoframework. Would that mean generics could work right now in a release build without a debugger attached?

Comment: I tried it out myself: the VS extension doesn't hang, but the device reboots before running the C# program.

Comment: Yes, they should be a pretty usable shape. Through testing is waiting for debugging features. ;)
But you would need a build from the develop-generics branch.